# Is selection sort faster that insertion sort in reverse arrays?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort, selection-sort

In the case that we have a reversely ordered array, is selection sort faster than insertion sort?

I think selection sort is faster because we have `O(n^2)` search and `O(n)` swap but in insertion sort we have `O(n^2)` swap and `O(n^2)` search.

Can anyone please tell me if I'm correct or not?
Thanks

Comment: You will need to count comparisons and element assignments for both alternatives, and compare. Both are $O(n^2)$, as you note, thus handwaving argumentś won't be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done some benchmarking on this topic on my own Python implementations. It depends heavily on what type of input you have. I found that Insertion Sort is slightly faster (like 3%) for randomly ordered input, but Selection sort is much faster for reverse sorted input. I had always heard that Selection Sort is the faster of the two, but my own benchmarks on my implementations didn't reflect that.